# React.PureComponent not implementing shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I might be missing something, but I have a component like this

```
export default MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    // ...
}
```

When MyComponent is part of another components render method, MyComponent re-renders every time the parent renders, even when the props/state are unchanged. So it seems changing from `React.Component` to `React.PureComponent` did not make the component "pure".

I tried adding

```
console.info(this.shouldComponentUpdate)
```

inside the one of the components methods, and it says it is undefined. Isn't `React.PureComponent` supposed to add a shallow-comparing `shouldComponentUpdate` method?

This has now happened with React **15.5.4** and **15.6.0**

Answer (score 4):

A PureComponent doesn't declare the `shouldComponentUpdate` directly. You can't visit it with `this.shouldComponentUpdate`. In the React source code there is a `shouldUpdate` variable:

(the source code below is simplified)

```
// default is true
var shouldUpdate = true;

if (inst.shouldComponentUpdate) {
  shouldUpdate = inst.shouldComponentUpdate(
    nextProps,
    nextState,
    nextContext,
  );
} else {
  // if it's a PureComponent
  if (this._compositeType === ReactCompositeComponentTypes.PureClass) {
    shouldUpdate =
      !shallowEqual(prevProps, nextProps) ||
      !shallowEqual(inst.state, nextState);
  }
}

// ...

if (shouldUpdate) {
  // re-render ..
}
```

Since it's just shallow equal, the code bellow returns false and you get a re-render:

```
const propA = { foo: 'bar' }
const nextPropA = { foo: 'bar' }

shallowEqual(propA, nextPropA) // false
```

So use objects and arrays carefully. To prove that PureComponent works, see this example (v15.6): https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/eRdzXM?editors=1010

Clicking the button won't trigger `Foo`'s render:

[image]

Here is another example that PureComponent may not work for you: https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/QgKKLg?editors=1010

The only difference is `<Foo someProp={{ foo: 'bar' }} />`

Because `{ foo: 'bar' } !== { foo: 'bar' }`, React will re-render every single time. So writing *inline* objects and arrays in props directly is not a good practice. A common mistake is writing inline style:

```
<Foo style={{ color: 'pink' }} />
```

In this case `Foo` will always re-render even if it's a PureComponent. If you are facing this problem you can simply extract and store the object somewhere, for example:

```
const someProp = { foo: 'bar' }

<Foo someProp={someProp} />
```

Since `someProp === someProp`, the PureComponent works.

Comment: Looks like this is caused by objects being passed as props. I understand the comparison issue, but feel going away from obj/arr props is not the best solution. This because data structures in the app in combination with reusable components often lead to passing lists of entities around, then sending one entity to a sub component for rendering, often along with a few other props. If I mix all entity data props with other (like behavioural) props, the prop definitions become a mess. I guess this means I need to create my own shouldComponentUpdate, so then I cant use React.PureComponent.

Comment: I meant writing objects and arrays inline. Updated the answer to make it clearer

Comment: Try not to use something like `<Foo style={{ color: 'pink' }} />` then PureComponent should work

Comment: @henit Not necessarily. You can also extract all state to the top and use immutables (e.g. the redux architecture). That will make the whole concept of pure rendering much easier to implement.

Comment: Hmm, right now I have an object with a set of props (like { id: 1234, name: 'My name' }). Then when a component render MyComponent with that object in one of its props, a re-render with an immutable copy of the same object, but with the exact same content, triggers a re-render on a PureComponent. Is there any way to avoid that without making my own shouldComponentUpdate?

Comment: Sorry not quite understand. If the parent doesn't call setState to modify that object, MyComponent won't re-render. See https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/eRdRyG?editors=0010